# How to use Hibernate ORM 5.5.x.Final with Jakarta 9 on wildfly-preview-25.0.0.Final

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, wildfly, hibernate-ogm

Have been running Hibernate OGM (using MongoDB) for a number of years. Currently using WildFly 25.0.0.Final:

```
/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/modules/org/hibernate/ogm/internal/parboiled/5.4/asm-util-6.0.jar 
/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/modules/org/hibernate/ogm/internal/parboiled/5.4/parboiled-core-1.3.1.jar 
/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/modules/org/hibernate/ogm/internal/parboiled/5.4/asm-analysis-6.0.jar 
/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/modules/org/hibernate/ogm/internal/parboiled/5.4/parboiled-core-1.1.8.jar 
/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/modules/org/hibernate/ogm/internal/parboiled/5.4/parboiled-java-1.1.8.jar 
/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/modules/org/hibernate/ogm/internal/parboiled/5.4/asm-6.0.jar 
/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/modules/org/hibernate/ogm/internal/parboiled/5.4/asm-tree-6.0.jar 
/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/modules/org/hibernate/ogm/mongodb/5.4/hibernate-ogm-mongodb-5.4.1.Final.jar 
/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/modules/org/hibernate/ogm/mongodb/5.4/mongo-java-driver-3.12.10.jar 
/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/modules/org/hibernate/ogm/jipijapa/5.4.1.Final/hibernate-ogm-jipijapa-5.4.1.Final.jar 
/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/modules/org/hibernate/ogm/5.4/hibernate-ogm-core-5.4.1.Final.jar 
/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/modules/org/hibernate/hql/1.5.0.Final/hibernate-hql-lucene-1.5.0.Final.jar 
/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/modules/org/hibernate//hql/1.5.0.Final/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar 
/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/modules/org/hibernate/hql/1.5.0.Final/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar 
/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/modules/org/hibernate/hql/1.5.0.Final/hibernate-hql-parser-1.5.0.Final.jar
```

I want to migrate to Jakarta 9 using: wildfly-preview-25.0.0.Final.

I get this now:

```
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: WFLYJPA0057: PersistenceProvider 'org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence' not found
```

Looked at: https://in.relation.to/2021/06/02/hibernate-orm-550-final-release/ and downloaded:

> hibernate-release-5.5.8.Final.zip

persistence.xml is:

```
<persistence-unit name="goStopHandleMongoDBPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">

        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>

        <properties>
            <!-- <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.2"/> -->
            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.5"/>

            <!-- <property name="wildfly.jpa.hibernate.search.module" value="org.hibernate.search.orm:5.8"/> -->
            <property name="wildfly.jpa.hibernate.search.module" value="org.hibernate.search.orm:5.10"/>

            <!-- <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="JBossTS"/> -->
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAS"/> -->
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.grid_dialect" value="org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.MongoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="goStopHandleDB"/>

            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="127.0.0.1:27017"/>
        </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I can’t located where I can found the Jars for
Hibernate ORM 5.5.8.Final & deploy on:

```
modules/org/hibernate etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate OGM is not going to work with ORM 5.5 ([the latest version requires ORM 5.3](https://hibernate.org/ogm/releases/5.4/)).

Also, there hasn't been any progress on Hibernate OGM for a while and there are no future plans for it.

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Will ORM 5.3 work with Jakarta 9 on wildfly-preview-25.0.0.Final? Deleted post and re-entered. Has missed passed. Well & truly buggered after investing in ORM & OGM.