# Migrating to 'Morphia' from Hibernate OGM

Tags: java, mongodb, orm, morphia, hibernate-ogm

I have been running MongoDB (5.0.7) for a number of years with Hibernate ORM & OGM. Currently using '**org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:4.6.0**'. (2022.04.26)

Using WildFly 26.1.0.Final (Jakarta EE 8 Full) with OpenJDK 18.0.1. IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1, Gradle 7.4.2 & macOS Monterey 12.3.1.

I need to migrate to Jakarta 9. See "Hibernate OGM is not going to work with ORM 5.5 (the latest version requires ORM 5.3)." on:
[How to use Hibernate ORM 5.5.x.Final with Jakarta 9 on wildfly-preview-25.0.0.Final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69824241/how-to-use-hibernate-orm-5-5-x-final-with-jakarta-9-on-wildfly-preview-25-0-0-fi)

I am looking at using ODM '**Morphia 2.2.6**' ([dev.morphia.morphia:morphia-core:2.2.6](https://dev.morphia.morphia:morphia-core:2.2.6)) and trying to run the 'morphia/example/QuickTour.java':

https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia/blob/2.2.x/examples/src/test/java/dev/morphia/example/QuickTour.java

It compiles, but when I try & run it I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.getDescription()'
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.createCluster(DefaultClusterFactory.java:179)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl.createCluster(MongoClientImpl.java:190)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl.<init>(MongoClientImpl.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:112)
    at com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:40)
    at dev.morphia.example.QuickTour.main(QuickTour.java:23)
```

Have also tried with:

```
 final Datastore datastore = Morphia.createDatastore(MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017"), "morphia_example");
```

Any suggestions? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the driver are you using?  4.2.x is the earliest version currently being tested.

Comment: Currently using 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:4.5.1'

Comment: Have migrated back to "implementation("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:4.2.1".  Deployed my App EAR and Hibernate ORM & OGM work fine. Same error with "QuickTour"..

Comment: Curious.  i'll take a look.

Comment: In case you want to follow along:  https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia/issues/1871

Comment: Thanks. Anything I can do to assist let me know. Will follow #1871.

Comment: Everything seems to work with 4.2.x of the driver.  CI confirms the quicktour builds and runs with 4.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

"Schoolboy error" - Didn't add to Gradle:

```
"implementation group: "org.mongodb", name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "3.12.10"
```

So IntelliJ 'run' failed. Apologies!